# Convert Double to Scientific Notation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, math, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to convert a given double into scientific notation, and running into some problems. I cant seem to find much documentation on how to do it either. Currently I am using:

```
 var val = 500
 var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
 numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.ScientificStyle
 let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString("\(val)")
 println(number as Double?) 
 // Prints optional(500) instead of optional(5e+2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set NumberFormatter properties positiveFormat and exponent Symbol to format your string as you want as follow:

```
let val = 500
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .scientific
formatter.positiveFormat = "0.###E+0"
formatter.exponentSymbol = "e"
if let scientificFormatted = formatter.string(for: val) {
    print(scientificFormatted)  // "5e+2"
}
```

---

update: **Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

You can also create an extension to get a scientific formatted description from Numeric types as follow:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let scientific: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .scientific
        formatter.positiveFormat = "0.###E+0"
        formatter.exponentSymbol = "e"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    var scientificFormatted: String {
        return Formatter.scientific.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
print(500.scientificFormatted)   // "5e+2"
```

Comment: Can I convert the string back to a double but preserve the scientific notation?

Comment: Probably not as a Double is by definition not in scientific notation

Comment: You can create an extension to get a scientific description from your double

Comment: That is a great idea. Sorry for the nooby questions. I am new to all of this! Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Use `positiveFormat = "0.000E+0"` to output number as `1.100e-6` instead of `1.1e-6`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are printing the number... not the formatted number. You are calling `numberForString` instead of `stringForNumber`

```
var val = 500
var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.ScientificStyle
let numberString = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(val)
println(numberString)
```

Comment: Scientific notation refers to the string you get from the Double. But if you have a string in scientific notation, you can use the formatter to get the double back out of that string

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to the answer by [leo-dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) to Xcode 9 Swift 4:

```
extension Double {
    struct Number {
        static var formatter = NumberFormatter()
    }
    var scientificStyle: String {
        Number.formatter.numberStyle = .scientific
        Number.formatter.positiveFormat = "0.###E+0"
        Number.formatter.exponentSymbol = "e"
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        return Number.formatter.string(from :number) ?? description
    }
}
```